Transitivity of the homotopy
In Milnor’s book Topology from the differentiable viewpoint, smooth homotopy for functions $f$ and $g$ from $M$ to $N$ (where $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds of same dimension, the first being compact and the last connected) is defined as follows

A smooth homotopy between from $f$ to $g$ is a smooth map $F : M\times [0,1]\to Y$ such that $F(x,0)=f(x)$ and $F(x,1)=g(x)$

I wanted to prove that this notion is transitive (as a relation).
Here is my attempt :
Let $f$ bye smoothly homotopic to $g$ and $g$ smoothly homotopic to $h$. This means that there exists
$$
F(x,t) : M\times [0,1]\to N,\;\text{smooth}\:, F(x,0)=f(x)\quad\text{and}\quad F(x,1)=g(x)
$$
$$
G(x,t) : M\times [0,1]\to N,\;\text{smooth},\; G(x,0)=g(x)\quad\text{and}\quad G(x,1)=h(x)
$$
Now consider $H(x,t)= (1-t)F(x,t) + tG(x,t)$. This mapping is smooth and satisfy the homotopy condition.
I would like to know if it is correct, for me it seems very natural to consider this, but Milnor did not proceed in this way so I wondering if I am wrong.
Thank you a lot !

How is $H$ defined with values in an arbirary manifold $N$, instead of just $\mathbb{R}^n$?

@anomaly You are right, I did not think of this and there is no reason that it is in $N$. I will try to propose something more appropriate. Thank you a lot !

I suggest you check an algebraic topology textbook for a proof in the category of general topological spaces and try to imitate the argument. There will be a smoothness issue at $t=1/2$ that you will have to resolve.

@MoisheKohan Thank you for the suggestion, indeed the way to do it is simple and intuitive if we see the parameter $t$ as a time ! For $t=\frac{1}{2}$ I naively try to the see right and left derivative with respect to $t$ and they do not coincide indeed !

Right. This is the main issue. You have to modify the original homotopies a bit to resolve it.

@MoisheKohan  think it is okay now thanks to your guidance ! Thank you a lot !
